# Accepted answers in answer tab are hard to distinguish

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the [answers tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2161/dan-rasmussen?tab=answers) of a user's profile, the green vote-count of an accepted answer is hard to distinguish from the grey vote-count of the others. In the [user's summary](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2161/dan-rasmussen?tab=summary), accepted answers (and questions with accepted answers) are given a green background, which really helps. Is this background missing from the answers tab? Other sites like SO have the colored background on the tab.

Comment: This definitely is a bug. I'm fixing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed on dev. The change will be in the next production build.

Comment: This fix hasn't shown up for me yet - how long does it take production builds to go live?

Comment: @DanRasmussen It looks like the last live fix didn't do the job. I've put in another fix. I'll check after tonight's prod build. You should see it tomorrow morning EST.